# how to get one value from a table in the entity framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I need to get only one value from the table, I do it like this:

```
public DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
public ObservableCollection<Users> GetUsers
{
   get { return db.Users.Local; }
}
public WindowViewModel(Label userName)
{
    var us = GetUsers.Where(u => u.Id == 1) as Users;
    userName = us.Name.ToString();
}
```

But it does not work out the error: Additional information: The object reference does not point to an instance of the object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/218510/5246145

Comment: Sounds like a null reference exception, mayby this article will help; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: You need some basic LINQ knowledge.

Comment: Some usefull links
[LINQ: .NET Language-Integrated Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx)
----
[LINQ to Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/linq-to-entities)

Comment: `as Users;` should be `.FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you some direction

Do not use a propertie to get your data, use a method

like this:

```
//returns an enumeration of users filtered by the given expression
Public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(Expression<Func<User, bool>> expression)
{
    return db.Users.Where(expression);
}
// returns the first occurency of a user filtered by the given expression
Public User GetUser(Expression<Func<User, bool>> expression)
{
    return db.Users.FirstOrDefault(expression);
}
```

usage:

```
var user = GetUser(u => u.Id == 1);     // returns first occurency or null
var users = GetUsers(u => u.Id < 100);
```

and you have a `label`, it is an object, with properties where you should set the information, so set your `Name` to its `Content`:

```
public WindowViewModel(Label userName)
{
    var us = GetUser(u => u.Id == 1);
    userName.Content = us.Name.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. At me still a problem the second method again returns the same error: Additional information: The reference to the object does not point to an instance of the object.

Comment: this can help you ->  http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/introduction.aspx